# cifar10_quick_train_testのプーリング層の出力が整数ではない

Tags: python, 機械学習, 深層学習, caffe

caffeの`cifar10_quick_train_test`でプーリング層の出力が

```
OH = (H-FH)/S + 1
(32-3)/2 + 1
29/2 + 1
```

以上のような計算になり
割り切れない数になると思うのですが、どのような処理が行われているのでしょうか？

https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/cifar10/cifar10_quick_train_test.prototxt

```
layer {
  name: "conv1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "conv1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 32
    pad: 2
    kernel_size: 5
    stride: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.0001
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "pool1"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "pool1"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 2
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

割り切れない場合の対応は、ディープラーニングのフレームワーク（ソフトウェア）によって異なり、エラーを出力するものや最も近い整数に丸めるものがあります。

https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/128797ebe100dd87f375d2d30b0f649914d0fcc3/src/caffe/layers/pooling_layer.cpp#L91

このあたりを見ると、caffeはパラメーターで動作モードを変えられるようにしていますね。